# How do I store images with Backand and Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, backand

How exactly do I go about storing profile images for in the Users object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Backand server side add the "Backand Storage" action, with this code:

```
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {
  // upload file
  if (request.method == "POST"){
    var url = files.upload(parameters.filename, parameters.filedata);
    return {"url": url};
  }
  // delete file
  else if (request.method == "DELETE"){
    files.delete(parameters.filename);
    return {};    
  }
}
```

And on the client side you can use this code in Ionic, it is based to copy the code from here: [backand docs](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/apidocs/files/index.html#angular-client-code)

Comment: Great! But, how can I make it so that the uploaded file is linked to a specific id in the object?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Base64 encoded image to save in the user object.

Helpful articles covering this are [base64-images](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/base64-images.html) and [data-uris](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Hope it helps.